# Which files are needed from the mmenu download?

Tags: jquery, mmenu

General question for a newb to the plugin and to js. After unzipping the download, does the entire mmenu folder need to be uploaded into my sites root? I'm not certain if I copy the css and js files out of the dist or src folders only, or the entire mmenu folder and link to files within it.

Any help is much appreciated!